# Which hero is more effective to boost as Ana in Junkenstein Brawl?

Tags: overwatch

In terms of effectiveness in killing the minibosses that spawn periodically (Reaper, Roadhog, Mercy, and Junkrat) which hero is better to nano boost? For example would boosting a Soldier: 76 who is ulting help more than boosting a McCree who is ulting?

Answer (score 3):

You will definitely want to boost Mccree to take down the bosses, but not right as the boss spawns, especially in higher difficulties. The bosses have too much HP and will need longer than the full 10 seconds of charging to kill them with Deadeye even when boosted by Ana. You will want to chip down bosses before using Deadeye. All of the bosses have some way to heal aside from Junkenstein himself, so you will want Deadeye to be used to finish off the kill.

Soldier does get guaranteed hits with his ultimate, but they are limited to body shots which simply don't deal enough damage even with the boost in damage.

Hanzo is too heavily dependant on accuracy since his arrows are not hitscan like Mccree and Soldier. I do not believe his Ultimate gets more damage from being boosted. Even if it were, the bosses move around too much for it to be much help, again aside from Junkenstein who sticks to his small ledge.

Comment: I agree with this, and I like your reasoning as to why the other characters aren't as good. Soldier will have a much easier time just going for headshots, rather than trying to nano-ult the bosses.

Answer (score 2):

McCree, no question about it. His ult does by far the most damage, charging by 170 damage every second before firing.